# Are all objects on sequence diagram should be designed in class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm working on sequence & class diagram for education website, should all objects in sequence diagram be a class in Class diagram?

For example in sequence diagram for registration process I need an object called "Data Base" which needed for saving information of user, should "Date base" be a class in class diagram? and what can be its functions? Is it just load & save?

Comment: The elements in your sequence diagram represent elements of your system design. And of course, any element of your system should somehow be represented within your class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Database would be a class in Class Diagram and its functions can be validation() , generatingErrorMessage() etc.

Comment: Moreover the operations in the classes directly correspond to messages in sequence diagrams.

Comment: Unless those messages are asynchronous signals.

Comment: @jiml then they correspond with receptions.

Comment: One remark. Do not call class Database, unless you're describing database engine. In your case it should be UserRegister.

Comment: Exactly my point. Sometimes messages correspond to signal receptions, loosening Thomas' rigid statement.

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends on the level of formality, abstraction, and the purpose of your UML model.

[Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlMode.html) talks about UML as Sketch, UML as Blueprint, and UML as Programming Language.

The terminology has gotten some good usage; and I think 'UML as Sketch' in particular has emerged as a popular mode, with the goal of human-to-human communication about the design of a system; not necessarily a formal engineering specification (i.e. a blueprint), nor suitable as an input to a code generator (i.e. a programming language).

If you want to use UML in Sketch mode, which is perfectly valid, then it's not a requirement for your sequence diagrams to use only the classes defined in your class diagram.  In fact, some of the objects/lifelines in a sequence diagram aren't class instances at all:

- They may be "actors" defined in a use case diagram (or not). Actors are often people, and as such are represented as stick figures. "End user" is a common actor to include in a sequence diagram. Plenty of [examples here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sequence%20diagram%20actor&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq67Oc_OzQAhVHlxQKHXvlCRAQsAQIJw&biw=1024&bih=482).
- They may be external systems, like a database, that are not defined in your class model. Your system might have a class, or set of classes, to abstract the database, i.e. a "data access layer" or DAL. But then again, your system might not have a DAL; and even if it does, you might still want your sequence diagram to show the interactions across the boundary, between the DAL and the actual database.

Using UML as a sketch, the methods implemented by external actors or system components are really up to you.  You could show a database query as `execute query`, or something more specific, like an actual SQL statement.  The "correctness" of your diagram is in its ability to communicate effectively with your audience, at the right level of detail and formality.

Comment: Amazing answer, becuase it clears it for me that when one talks about SD, they might be referring to two different things which serve different purposes at different levels of abstractions. I think this should be the accepted answer instead! Thanks.